# Get angle that is out of a range

Tags: trigonometry, circles, angle

I would like to make a function that, given an angle and a range, obtains an angle that doesn't fall in the ranges $[0º, ±range]$ and $[180º, ±range]$.

I think that the following picture better explains the problem:

[image: Problem image]

If the input angle falls inside the red area, I need to return the nearest angle from the green area.

I need to support both clock- and counterclockwise (negative angles).

The following method does the trick for a range of 30º, but I'm sure that there is a better solution using trigonometric functions:

```
    internal static double GetAngleOutOfRange(double angle, double range)
    {
        if (angle >= 0 && angle <= 30)
            return 30;

        if (angle < 0 && angle >= -30)
            return -30;

        if (angle <= -150 && angle >= -180)
            return -150;

        if (angle >= 150 && angle <= 180)
            return 150;

        if (angle <= -180 && angle >= -210)
            return -210;

        if (angle >= 180 && angle <= 210)
            return 210;

        if (angle <= -330 && angle >= -360)
            return -330;

        if (angle >= 330 && angle <= 360)
            return 330;

        return angle;
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand the last three "if" statements in your code. They deviate from the pattern of the first five. Also, must the output angle follow the convention of the input angle or can it just be in the range (-180,180)?

Comment: There was a bug in the code. Now it's edited. Also, the last two statements allow to support angles from +-335 to +-365. For me, 364º are the same than -1º.

Comment: There's $360$ degrees in a circle, not $365$.And you didn't answer my range question.

Comment: What a shame! Sorry for my stupidity. 365 are days in a year!! :-D I fixed the code, sorry for that. About the range question, I think that I must follow the convention, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with *sin* and *cos* is indeed easier

```
s = sin( angle )

if |s| >= |sin( range )|  return angle

r = | range |
res = cos( angle ) < 0 ? 180-r : r

return s < 0 ? -res : +res
```

|x| is $|x|$ and `cond ? a : b` gives `a` if `cond` is true, `b` otherwise.

Comment: Compact solution that worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the output angle can just be in the range $(-180,180)$ and that the $range$ is in the interval $(0,90)$, here's some pseudo code that should work:

> If $\; abs(\sin (angle)) < \sin (range) \;$ then
> $\{$
> $\quad $if $\cos(angle) \gt 0$ then
> $\qquad angle=range$
> $\quad $ else
> $\qquad angle=180-range$
>
> $\quad $if $\sin(angle) \lt 0$ then
> $\qquad angle=-angle$
> $\}$

Comment: I was wondering if you could use a cross product of cosine and sine and check if the input angle is within the image of the cross product. Would that work? That is, $\cos(x) \times \sin(x)$, where $x \in [\theta-  \beta, \theta + \beta]$.

Comment: Not sure I understand. What is $\theta$ and $\beta$?

Comment: $\theta$ is the fixed angle used for the symmetry and $\beta$ is the range to extend from the symmetry. I'm not sure if crossing the functions map to the angles that fall in the range that OP wants to avoid.

Comment: It wouldn't map uniquely. Try it with e.g. 20 degrees (forbidden zone) and approx. 83.6096 degrees (accepted zone).